# ERROR : use '-gpu off' to disable it in Android studio 2.1.3

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.2

I am on Windows 7, `Android Studio 2.1.3`. I found this error on output console while running `Hello world` application:

> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

While this pop up.
 [Error picture is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arakf.png) Am i missing something?

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager

Now click the pencil icon of the emulator and uncheck `Use Host GPU` option.

[image]

**UPDATE:** For newer *Android Studio 3.0*, Google has removed this option and put this instead.

[image]

And the explanation is right there as well.

[image]

So, its best to set it on `Automatic` if you're unsure which one to go for.

Comment: But its giving error for automatic... can u suggest something.?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card? Or just on-board graphics memory?

Comment: I had to set it to `Software ...`. Otherwise it failed.